# How to condition on odd or even across rows in dataframe

Tags: dataframe

I am looking to create a new variable based on the nature of other variables in the same observation

Column C should be "Keep" if all values in Columns A and B are not each Even or not each Odd, otherwise value in Column C should be remove.  Ideally, I'd just like the result to retain only the "Keeps"

I've typed out what I want to achieve programmatically in Column C

```
b<-data.frame(matrix(c(1, 3, 4, 5, 2, 8), nrow=3, ncol=2))
c<-data.frame(c("remove","keep","remove"))
x<-cbind(b,c)
names(x)<-c("A","B","C")
x
```

Ideally, I'd just like the result to retain only the "Keeps"

Comment: anyone?  Bueller?